# TOMCAT - org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer SEVERE: Catalina.stop:

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm facing this error while trying to call shutdown.sh on Tomcat.
Tomcat in on an internal server on 192.168.1.240:8080

The stack trace is

```
Aug 29, 2016 5:14:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop: 
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Can't assign requested address
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:450)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:400)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:487)
```

And Tomcat does not stops...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Tomcat :java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698802/apache-tomcat-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you run out of available ports or the port of stop tomcat is already occup. and you can kill the process to stop tomcat